# Controlling a 5W 12V DC water pump

Tags: pwm, motor-controller, fluid-pump

I have just bought [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00OIHLTME/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A2SCHN5ORI8W2E&psc=1) pump to circulate coolant through an experiment. I would like to control the pump output as it doesn't have any control on it.

It is being powered from a 12V 0.5A power supply.

How would be best to go about this? Voltage control or PWM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. My reccomendation for this would be using 'Current control' not voltage control using a MOSFET, and POTENTIOMETER:
   See: [How to build the simplest DC Motor Speed Controller(Using Potentiometer and MOSFET)Updated](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipiDHD4YEMM)
2. Alternatively You could use an adjustable DC-to-DC control module to set the voltage, however this will have a small dropout voltage which may not be desirable du to the reduction in maximum voltage output.
3. You could use a large, high-power potentiometer, but this is expensive.
4. If you are using a uController, then PWM control of the Motor will be an easy task. You would likely just need a MOSFET, uController (eg arduino) and a diode.

Comment: I have got a IRF9520 MOSFET which I believe is P-channel, where as the? IRF540 in the example is N-channel. Does this mean I can't use this? Or can I modify the circuit to work with it?

Comment: I would have a look at the circuit outlined on this Page: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html under the heading: "P-channel MOSFET Switch"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the output then the other option is to let the pump run at max efficiency / flow / pressure and control the coolant flow with a bypass valve arrangement... It depends what you want to achieve and what may be easier to achieve.