# Controlling Flow/Pressure of a Diaphragm Pump

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, fluid-pump

I searched for similar questions; especially [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/324219/controlling-a-5w-12v-dc-water-pump), but I don't know if the answers apply to my question as well.

I am a software guy and have almost no clue about electrical engineering. I am as well a novice in diaphragm water pumps. Please bear with me.

However, I want to control the flow rate/pressure of [this diaphragm pump](http://www.seaflo.com/en-us/product/detail/601.html) (model number: SFDP1-010-040-21). Here's the pump diagram (see the link):

[image]

12V DC, min. 1.6A to max. 4A. The pump is only used for a few minutes, overheating won't be a serious issue.

I need a hint into the correct direction. My assumptions/question:

- The flow rate/pressure can be increased/decreased by modifiyng the amps? Like the datasheet suggests.
- How would I do this? Other users claimed to control this via PWM or DC Motor Drivers?

Comment: DC motor drivers probably use PWM

Comment: You need to also have the [curve representing pressure/flow characteristics of the SYSTEM](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/pump-system-curves-d_635.html) (what this is pumping into).  Where the pump and system curves intersect is where you will operate.  (This is off topic for this stack.)